# Posso chamar colegas para a comunidade?

Tags: debate, suporte

Me parece que temos muito poucos usuários realmente ativos na comunidade e fazem e respondem perguntas, gostaria de saber existe algum problema em convidar colegar para o beta privado? Acho que quando mais questões de diferentes usuários tivermos mais legal fica o site certo?

Answer (score 11):

Curto e grosso!

> ### **DEVE!!!**

O sistema de convite que tem na coluna direita das páginas de perguntas servem para isso mesmo. Incentivo a todos convidar o máximo de pessoas que puder.

Sempre é bom dar uma explicadinha rápida que ajustes estão sendo feitos, mas o site está funcional e todos podem participar, e o que mais achar necessário de acordo com a experiência de cada um com o SO (se você souber).

Hoje devemos ter mais [sapos](http://www.qdivertido.com.br/verconto.php?codigo=13)* que [assinantes originais da proposta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese).

<sub>*tecnicamente nós estamos organizando a festa e eles é que estão sendo convidados mas vale o espírito :)</sub>

Comment: Qual a diferença entre pedir para essa pessoa criar uma conta, acessar a proposta, visitar o site e criar uma conta, ao invés de convidar uma pessoa pelo formulário?

Comment: @Zignd Bem pouca, porém eu acho que não mais é possível fazer commit. Está lá no site: "*This proposal is now in the Beta phase — no more commitments accepted!*"

Comment: Seria interessante haver uma medalha para quem convida um certo número de pessoas, e outra para quem tem seus convites aceitos. Isso pode é mais um ponto a motivar o pessoal a convidar.